# Mysql why 12.3 < 12.3 is true

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
-------OT-----------
- id        - INT  -
- from_time - FLOAT-
- to_time   - FLOAT-
--------------------
```

Save value

```
- id - from_time -- to_time --
-------------------------
- 1  - 8.3       -- 12.3    --
-------------------------
```

My SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM (`OT` as wt) WHERE ( (12.3 < wt.to_time) );
```

Expected it to return no record.
But it actually returned record id = 1.

I have tried with 0.3 to 15.3 and it is same but with 16.6 it returns no records.
My MySQL version is 5.6.23.

Please help me, and why that happened?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in fiddle for us?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - I don't think JSFiddle handles MySQL.

Comment: You could try `12.3 < CAST(wt.to_time AS DECIMAL(3,1))` but storing as a decimal would be best..

Comment: @BSMP sqlfiddle does

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating point precision is not exact science. You should use the `DECIMAL` datatype instead of `FLOAT`

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: To support your answer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: I don't think this is the case because Op said that situation is the same for 15.3

Comment: Thanks Tuan Anh so much!

Comment: Created local DB and Table to match OPs schema, tested comparison given the sql statement above (to make sure it wasn't some arbitrary string comparison issue or something) and any comparison greater than 12.3 returns no records. Could @ChungLe confirm the range was indeed 0.3-15.3? I am on MySql version 5.6.24.

Answer (score 1):

@tuananh is absolutely right.

So you can change type of your column or change your query:

```
SELECT * FROM (`OT` as wt) WHERE ( 12.3  < CAST(wt.to_time AS DECIMAL(15,4)) );
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01434/5

But it would be much better to change your column type to simlify future use and to increase performance of queries you will create. If you use a lot of `CAST` it will slow down query execution time.

Comment: I made the same fiddle around the same time, but included more rows for testing.